# Splitting indexes of arrays and storing it into a new array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, reverse

I'm trying to input a series of names and store them into an array to have ready to print reversed when needed. For example,

Input:

```
Bill Cosby[enter]   
Jack Bob[enter]
```

Output:

```
Cosby, Bill    
Jack, Bob
```

This is how I'm tackling the issue, I decided to start by storing all of the names into an array (`_StudentNames`) and then I planned on splitting the array at every space and storing the separate names into a new array (`_StudentNamesSplit`) which would be twice as big. After that, when a name needed to be printed, I would simply do something like
 `out.print(_StudentNamesSplit[1] + ", " + _StudentNamesSplit[0]);`

I understand the issue I have is that with this code, only the last name that was entered would be stored into the array.

I'm open to any suggestions to solving this problem in particular or even an entirely different method as to going about this task. It would be great if there was a way to store the name reversed with the comma into one element of an array but maybe that would be a bit advanced?

```
    out.print("How many students are in the class? ");    
    int _numStudents = scanInt.nextInt();    
    String[] _StudentNames = new String[_numStudents];      
    String[] _StudentNamesSplit = new String[_numStudents * 2];     
    for (int i = 0; i < _numStudents; ++i)   
    {    
        _StudentNames[i] = scanString.nextLine();   
        _StudentNamesSplit = _StudentNames[i].split(" ");    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use a Student class (such as this) -

```
public static class Student {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = (firstName != null) ? firstName
        .trim() : "";
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = (lastName != null) ? lastName
        .trim() : "";
  }

  public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
  }

  public Student(String[] names) {
    if (names != null && names.length == 2) {
      setFirstName(names[0]);
      setLastName(names[1]);
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName;
  }
}
```

And you'd use it like this (note that it's now unbounded, and the `lastname, firstname` is handled by the `Student.toString()` method -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  List<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();
  try {
    System.out.println("Enter student names [firstname lastname], CTRL-D to stop.");
    String line;
    while ((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
      if (line != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        String[] names = line.split(" ");
        if (names.length == 2) {
          al.add(new Student(names));
        }
      }
    }
  } finally {
    for (Student student : al) {
      System.out.println(student);
    }
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is an array with names reversed (e.g."Cosby, Bill"), then the following short snippet suffices:

```
public static giveReversedNames(String[] names) {
    String[] reversedNames = new String[names.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        List<String> rev_pair = Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(name.split(" ")));
        reversedNames[i] = Joiner.on(",").join(rev_pair);
    }
    return reversedNames;
}
```

I am using `Collections#reverse()` and `Joiner#join()`, but of course, you could use any other method in their place.

Answer (score 1):

can't you compose the string in revers order with the "," and input that into the **array** **_StudentNamesSplit**.Also as you can't determine the size of array, I think it's better to use a **ArrayList** in implimenting this. For instance you can use something like this.

```
Scanner sn= new Scanner(System.in);

    String unformatted_name;
    ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> reverse_names=new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder formatted_name = new StringBuilder();

    while(sn.hasNext()){

        unformatted_name=sn.nextLine();
        for (String retval: unformatted_name.split(" ", 2)){
            names.add(retval);

          }

        formatted_name.append(names.get(1).toString());
        formatted_name.append(',');
        formatted_name.append(names.get(0).toString());

        reverse_names.add(formatted_name.toString());


    }
```

As you have no idea on how much lines you are going to enter its is better to use **ArrayList**.

Answer (score 0):

`_StudentNamesSplit` just have to be a multi-dimensional array:

```
String[][] _StudentNamesSplit = new String[_numStudents][2];
```

Then when you split, you put the result of the split at the index `i`:

```
_StudentNamesSplit[i] = _StudentNames[i].split(" ");
```

And when you write the student name, you do it like this:

```
out.print(_StudentNamesSplit[studentIndex][1] + ", " + _StudentNamesSplit[studentIndex][0]);
```

You could go with your initial idea of an array twice as big, also. The reason it did not work is that you put the result of the last split in the variable `_StudentNamesSplit`, essentially replacing the previous data. Instead you would have to copy the split result in the array. The method with a multidimensional array is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one Array to store your data (does it need to be an Array? Why don't you use a List?). Then, for each name entered, you process it (just when it's entered) and store them with the format you want.
Then, to print them all, just go through your array and print each element.

By the way, each element in your Array can contain spaces so you don't need to create an array twice as big as the number of elements to insert.